# Elasticsearch Score document by the same value of the field

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say you have 5 products from same users and u you list them
If a **user_id** (field) have same value in 5 documents, i want the fifth document to have the least document score
the score should gradually decrease from the first to the fifth

**expected score**

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_type": "product",
    "_id": "74162",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "user_id": 90
    } 
 },
 {
    "_type": "product",
    "_id": "6",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "user_id": 35
    } 
 }
 {
    "_type": "product",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 0.9,
    "_source": {
      "user_id": 90
    } 
 },
 {
    "_type": "product",
    "_id": "3",
    "_score": 0.8,
    "_source": {
      "user_id": 90
    } 
 },
{
    "_type": "product",
    "_id": "4",
    "_score": 0.7,
    "_source": {
      "user_id": 90
    } 
 },
{
    "_type": "product",
    "_id": "5",
    "_score": 0.6,
    "_source": {
      "user_id": 90
    } 
 }
```

]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the score other than ordering results? if not then you can just order by user_id

Also can you specify what defines the relevance of these results?

Comment: its doesnt matter  score or other field to sort

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sorting by `_score` and `user_id` will be OK for you:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "sort" : [
    { "_score"  : "desc" },
    { "uder_id" : "asc" }
  ],
  "query" : {
    //your query here
  }
}
```

Source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-request-sort.html

Comment: sorry  its not. .

Comment: So I probably do not understand what you want

Comment: i want to affect score by duplicating fields

Comment: Please take a look at script_score (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-script-score). You can use it to affection score. Something like that?